# Add a 2nd Series to an Excel chart using C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I am trying to add two series to an Excel chart. I am able to add one series to the chart with this code. How can i add one more series to my chart?

```
worksheet.Select(Type.Missing);
Excel.Range chartRange;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)worksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

chartRange = worksheet.get_Range("B2", "B10");
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
var series = (Excel.Series)chartPage.SeriesCollection(1);
series.Values = chartRange;
chartRange = worksheet.get_Range("A2", "A10");
series.XValues = chartRange;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the C# for it, but in VBA I would use something like:

```
With ChartPage.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C10")
End With
```